# Toggle class on a secondary selector when using foreach

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked a question before but deleted it as it wasn't well written and didn't provide all the necessary details, so here's hoping I have this time.

I currently have an accordion-like menu where there is a toggle button to show/hide content. I have used a forEach function to listen for a 'click' on said toggle button but it currently only applies a class to that button to change its styling to open/close, I'm trying to figure out how to also toggle a class on another element related to the button (this element is a sibling of the toggle buttons parent - see HTML markup).

As you will be able to see, I can toggle the background color of each button independently.

HTML:

```
<nav class="category-menu">
  <div class="category-menu__item">
    <div class="category-menu__link">
      <a href="#">Group</a>
      <button class="category-menu__toggle">
        <span class="bar bar--one"></span>
        <span class="bar bar--two"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="category-submenu">
      <div class="category-submenu__item">
        <div class="category-submenu__link"><a href="#">List</a></div>
        <div class="category-supersubmenu">
          <div class="category-supersubmenu__item">
            <div class="category-supersubmenu__link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="category-supersubmenu__item">
            <div class="category-supersubmenu__link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="category-menu__item">
    <div class="category-menu__link">
      <a href="#">Group</a>
      <button class="category-menu__toggle">
        <span class="bar bar--one"></span>
        <span class="bar bar--two"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="category-submenu">
      <div class="category-submenu__item">
        <div class="category-submenu__link"><a href="#">List</a></div>
        <div class="category-supersubmenu">
          <div class="category-supersubmenu__item">
            <div class="category-supersubmenu__link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="category-supersubmenu__item">
            <div class="category-supersubmenu__link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.category-menu {
  width: 50rem;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.category-menu__link {
  min-height: 3rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.category-menu__link a {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  line-height: 1.15;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.category-menu__toggle {
  width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar {
  display: block;
  height: 0.25rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar--one {
  transform: translateY(50%) rotate(90deg);
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar--two {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.category-submenu {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: var(--bluegrey-300);
}
.category-submenu__link {
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.category-submenu__link a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-supersubmenu {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.category-supersubmenu__link {
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.category-supersubmenu__link a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-menu__toggle--open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
const catTogglers = document.querySelectorAll(".category-menu__toggle");
catTogglers.forEach(function (catToggle) {
  catToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    catToggle.classList.toggle("category-menu__toggle--open");
  });
});
```

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/MartynMc/pen/oNweJwE)

EDIT:

I have tried using this, but it toggles the class on ALL elements with the class of **.category-submenu**:

```
const catTogglers = document.querySelectorAll('.category-menu__toggle');
const subMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.category-submenu');

catTogglers.forEach(function(catToggle) {
  catToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    catToggle.classList.toggle('category-menu__toggle--open');
    subMenus.forEach(function(subMenu) {
      subMenu.classList.toggle('category-submenu--open');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to switch the child's class at the button, right?

If so, you can find the child as follows

```js
catToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const child = catToggle.querySelectorAll('.bar.bar--one')[0]
  child.classList.toggle('new-child-class')
  catToggle.classList.toggle('category-menu__toggle--open')
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any way I can select the sibling of the current classes parent? The element I want to toggle another class on is not a child of the button class. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes you can. Look at my code. You need use method `querySelectorAll` from parent instead of `document`

Answer (score 0):

- i think that you want to change the icon to close icon when clicking on the button there's too many ways to do that

1. **Toggle class to the button**_

- We Will add class called `timesIco` like the following

```
.category-menu__toggle, .timesIco {
  width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.timesIco > span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(50%);
}
.timesIco > span:nth-child(2) { 
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

- So the whole css will be like that

```
.category-menu {
  width: 50rem;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.category-menu__link {
  min-height: 3rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.category-menu__link a {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  line-height: 1.15;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.category-menu__toggle, .timesIco {
  width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar {
  display: block;
  height: 0.25rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar--one {
  transform: translateY(50%) rotate(90deg);
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar--two {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.timesIco > span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(50%);
}
.timesIco > span:nth-child(2) { 
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
    
.category-submenu {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: var(--bluegrey-300);
}
.category-submenu__link {
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.category-submenu__link a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-supersubmenu {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.category-supersubmenu__link {
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.category-supersubmenu__link a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-menu__toggle--open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

- Then in your JS replace `category-menu__toggle--open` with `timesIco` like the following

```
const catTogglers = document.querySelectorAll(".category-menu__toggle");
catTogglers.forEach(function (catToggle) {
  catToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    catToggle.classList.toggle("timesIco");
  });
});
```

2. **Toggle class to the children**

- in this step there's too many ways to do that in JS you can use `this.children` or `this.getElementsByTagName` or `this.querySelectorAll`, etc.. but if you want to use `forEach` method you will be need to use `querySelectorAll`
- firstly we will create 2 classes called `class1`, `class2` like the following

```
.class1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(50%);
}
.class2 { 
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

- The Whole CSS

```
    .category-menu {
  width: 50rem;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.category-menu__link {
  min-height: 3rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.category-menu__link a {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  line-height: 1.15;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.category-menu__toggle {
  width: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar {
  display: block;
  height: 0.25rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar--one {
  transform: translateY(50%) rotate(90deg);
}
.category-menu__toggle .bar--two {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.class1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(50%);
}
.class2 { 
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
    
.category-submenu {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: var(--bluegrey-300);
}
.category-submenu__link {
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.category-submenu__link a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-supersubmenu {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.category-supersubmenu__link {
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
.category-supersubmenu__link a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-menu__toggle--open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

- Then add your JS - There's a new function called `changeClass` to toggle the children classes

```
function changeClass(element, checkClass, newClass) {
  if(element.classList.contains(checkClass)) {
    element.classList.remove(checkClass)
    element.classList.add(newClass)
  } else if(element.classList.contains(newClass)) {
    element.classList.remove(newClass)
    element.classList.add(checkClass)
  }
}
const catTogglers = document.querySelectorAll(".category-menu__toggle");
catTogglers.forEach(function (catToggle) {
  catToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let spans = this.querySelectorAll("span")
    spans.forEach(function(span) {
        changeClass(span, "bar--one", "class1")
        changeClass(span, "bar--two", "class2")
    }) 
  });
});
```

- but if you just want to toggle icons it's will be better to use `font awesome`